# How do I evaluate a CNTK model trained using sample SequenceClassification code

Tags: python, cntk

I used the code given at https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/v2.0/Examples/SequenceClassification/SimpleExample/Python/SequenceClassification.py to train a model. How do I evaluate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it by following way:

```
import cntk as C
from cntk.ops.functions import load_model # Note this
...
...
# saved the model after epochs
for i in range(500):
    mb = reader.next_minibatch(minibatch_size, input_map=input_map)
    trainer.train_minibatch(mb)
    classifier_output.save("model.dnn") # Note this
...
...
# loading the model
model = load_model("model.dnn") # Note this

# converted sentence to numbers and given as sequence
predScores = model(C.Value.one_hot([[1,238,4,4990,7223,1357,2]], 50466)) # Note this
predClass = np.argmax(predScores)
print(predClass)
```

where `[[1,238,4,4990,7223,1357,2]]` is the sequence of index of words in vocabs (basically the kind of sequence on which training had happened, and `50466` is the size of vocab.

Comment: This answer is good but would be better if it demonstrated how to tie a reader to evaluation.  I can't find an example that reads a ctf file, evaluates the examples using the model, and outputs the predictions and raw scores.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to evaluate a model in Python, please see the page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/how-do-i-evaluate-models-in-python). If you want use your model in other languages, e.g. C++/C#, you can find details in the [Model Evalaution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/CNTK-Evaluation-Overview) page.

Thanks,

Comment: it was not very clear from those pages. I added the way I finally resolved it.

Comment: The python example that's linked assumes we are using numpy for inputs, and only evaluates a single example. How do we batch evaluate a labeled validation file in ctf format?

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely when you are training your model in CNTK you don't need to employ the **create_reader/Minibatch** paraphernalia. Mostly because test/production files are usually quite small. Model evaluation is actually pretty straightforward:

```
import cntk as C
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

model = C.load_model(path_to_where_the_model_is_saved) # load your CNTK model

ds = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=",") # load your data of course
                                          # we are assuming all data come 
                                          # together in a single matrix

X = ds.values[:,0:28].astype('float32') # ensures the right type for CNTK
Y = ds.values[:,28].astype('float32')   # last column is the label

X= X / 255 # perform any necessary transformation if any

pred = model(X) # evaluate your test data

pred[pred > 0.5]=1
pred[pred!=1]=0
maxa=np.mean(Y==pred)

print("Accuracy {} ".format(maxa*100.0))
```